# RequestParam and sessions Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

i have one question i'm using

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String getUser(@RequestParam("id"), Model model){

  }
```

this means that when i'll give the url/user?id=1

that will give me back some data.
Now in the login i'm taking this id and i save it in a session.

```
   session.setAttribute("userId", result.getBody().getId());
```

and i want when a user click at a tab automatically to be bind the id with the attribute stored in the session. i.e. lets say that the userId has as value 1. Then when i'll click on the tab to redirected automatically to:url/user?id=1
How can i do this?

For the tab i have this one:

```
<a href="<c:url value='/user'/>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
<a href="<c:url value='/user?id=${userId}'/>"> ...</a>
```

and for SpringMVC, I suggest you use the Restful url like `/usr/1`, 
the action can be

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}")
public String show(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
  ...
}

//link
<a href="<c:url value='/user/${userId}'/>"> ...</a>
```

Comment: very close.actually i needed :<s:url value='/user?id=${userId}'/>. I need to import the :<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>.But your logic is correct.+1.Because The main difference between Spring’s <s:url> and JSTL’s <c:url> is that <s:url>
supports parameterized URL paths.I just found it

Answer (score 1):

Like @donnior asnwered `@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}")` is the best thing I have come accross.
It provides a very clean and secure way to navigate to a url in Spring.

I recommend you to use that. :)

Comment: Absolutely. It gives you neat and clean URL. :-)